# system("echo -e $str") can not been output rightly in perl

Tags: perl, echo, system

I write a simple perl script like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $str = "hello\nworld";
my $cmd = "echo -e $str";
system($cmd);
```

and output is :

```
-e hello
sh: 2: world: not found
```

which is not expected. And what I want is this:

```
hello
world
```

Notes that "echo -e" can work correclty, because when I run following command,

```
echo -e "hello\nworld"
```

the output is correct.

any solutions ?

Comment: Because `echo -e` is not portable, this is a particularly poor example. For anything real, everything `echo` can do, you can do more easily in Perl itself. Perhaps you should use a different example, perhaps closer to the real code you want to run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you print out `$cmd` after you set it, you'll see this:

```
echo -e hello
world
```

... and if you paste that into the shell you'll get similar error messages, although without the `-e`.

The first problem is that when it gets to the shell, the string is missing both the quotation marks and the non-literal newline.  Try this:

```
my $str = "hello\\nworld";
my $cmd = "echo -e '$str'";
```

In this particular case, you can get away with just the quotation marks - there will be a literal newline inside the argument to `echo`, but that's legal as long as it's quoted.

However, you will still get a literal `-e` in the output and no interpretation of the `\n` as a newline. That's because perl is running `/bin/echo`, not the `echo` built into bash.  If you want to use bash's builtin, you have to tell perl to run `bash` explicitly. But that means passing the echo command itself inside an argument to bash, which introduces *another* level of quoting to deal with.

The best bet here (and everywhere, really) is to use the multiple-argument version of `system`; that bypasses the first shell level and executes the command directly.  We still have to deal with the newline:

```
my $str = "hello\nworld";                 # literal newline
(my $escaped_str = $str) =~ s,\n,\\n,g;    # escaped newline
```

In order to get the desired behavior from the shell, we need to embed the string in single quotes in the shell command, because anything in single quotes is taken completely literally by the shell.  In this case we just assigned the string from a literal in the Perl code, so we know exactly what it contains, and it doesn't contain apostrophes. But if it might ever contain apostrophes, we should run it through another escape pass to quote them, so it's safe to embed in single quotes:

```
$escaped_str =~ s,','\\'',g;              # quote any embedded apostrophes
```

There may be other characters you wish to replace with escapes, too - perhaps tab or carriage return. This would be the place to make those changes as well.

Use the escaped string to build the bash command:

```
my $command = "echo -ne '$escaped_str'";  # bash command to echo string
```

Doing manual search/replaces like this is error-prone; there are a lot of edge cases to consider. So you may also want to look at the CPAN module [`String::ShellQuote`](http://search.cpan.org/~rosch/String-ShellQuote-1.03/ShellQuote.pm), in which you can skip the manual escaping above and generate the escaped string from the original like this:

```
my $command = shell_quote("echo", "-ne", $str);
```

Once you have the escaped command string, use the multiple-argument `system` to run bash directly with that string as an argument:

```
system('bash', '-c', $command);
```

In general and more importantly, I would consider replacing whatever the shell command does with code in Perl itself; the result will be much easier to manage, and probably more portable and performant as well.

Comment: thx, the output is like this when i using your recommand command:
`-e hello
world`
But when remove `-e` option (`"ehco  $cmd = "echo '$str' "`), it can work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $cmd = qq(echo -e "$str");
```

A new line in system's argument string is like a `;`. It separates commands. In order for that not to happen, you need to put it inside quotes.